# Google Translate API for reading text

Tags: android, cordova, google-translate

I am interested to know that is it possible that I can listen the text read by google translator through API I check the google translate API   ,

https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started#REST

but I didn’t get any useful thing , if its not possible than is there any way that I can do that I have to use it in mobile application using phone-gap .

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Google translate via API is a paid service you would not be able to query translations otherwise.

Assuming you do have access to the API, you would need another application/process/API to handle the text to speech action, as I don't believe that is part of the google translate API.

A possible solution is to use the Google translate API for translating and then appending the results of that operation to a text to speech API such as iSpeech.